# Oracle SQL Discrepancy: COUNT(*) vs Actual Result Set

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have an application that keeps track when a file is being “attempted” to move from one server to another, as well as when it has “succeeded” or “failed.” An "attempt" should always be paired with a "success" or "failure." However, there are 63 “orphaned” attempts, meaning there have been attempts without any success or failure reported. My first query shows where I got the **63** number to begin with: I take a count of all of the *attempts* and subtract the *successes* and *failures*-

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM e_table
    WHERE e_comment LIKE '%attempt%'
    AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
    AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
)
-
(
    SELECT
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM e_table
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%success%'
        AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
        AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
    )
    +
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM e_table
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%failure%'
        AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
        AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
    ) FROM dual
) AS orphaned_attempts FROM dual;
```

So my second query to get the specific **e_id** of the 63 attempts is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT e_id FROM e_table
    WHERE e_comment LIKE '%attempt%'
    AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
    AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
)
MINUS
(
    SELECT e_id FROM e_table
    WHERE e_comment LIKE '%success%'
    AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
    AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
)
MINUS
(
    SELECT e_id FROM e_table
    WHERE e_comment LIKE '%failure%'
    AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
    AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
);
```

What I need (and expect based on the first query’s result set) is to have a 63-row result set with one column containing the e_id of the orphaned attempts. Instead, I am getting only 49 rows back from the second query. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might have duplicate `e_id`s.  Sample data as well as desired results are helpful.

Comment: Change your second query to select * from... instead of select e_id from..., you should get 63 results. Then select e_id from this result set and look for duplicates as well as nulls.

Comment: My first instinct was to try DISTINCT calls in the query; there are no duplicates whatsoever.

Comment: @mathguy That does not provide the correct output, nor does it output 63 rows.

Comment: I know it doesn't provide the correct output, I meant for troubleshooting purposes. It should output 63 rows, you need to figure out why it doesn't. How many rows does it output, 49?

Comment: No, it returns 1000+. When I do individual selects for all categories, there are 5,460 attempts, 5,347 successes, and 50 failures.

Comment: As for duplicates, check `SELECT count(*), count(e_id), count(distinct e_id) FROM e_table WHERE e_comment LIKE '%attempt%' AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016' AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'`.

Comment: Instead of `COUNT(*)`, use `COUNT(DISTINCT e_id)`. Best of luck.

Comment: Why do you sometimes have `e_table` and sometimes have `e_event`?

Comment: Could you profile your data for me?  `SELECT attempts, successes, failures, row_count, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT e_id, SUM(CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%attempt%' THEN 1 END) AS attempts, SUM(CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%success%' THEN 1 END) AS successes, SUM(CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%failure%' THEN 1 END) AS failures, COUNT(*) AS row_count FROM e_table WHERE e_date >= '23-MAY-2016' AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016' GROUP BY e_id) summary GROUP BY attempts, successes, failures, row_count` Should help demonstrate duplicates, or single rows that match more than one state.  *(Such as `successful attempt`)*

Comment: Nice catch @MatBailie, I edited the post to make the table names more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.e_id,
    coalesce(attempts, 0) attempts,
    coalesce(successes, 0) successes,
    coalesce(failures, 0) failures
FROM
    (
        SELECT e_id, count(*) as attempts FROM e_table
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%attempt%' AND e_date BETWEEN '23-MAY-2016' AND '26-MAY-2016'
        GROUP BY e_id
    ) a
    full outer join
    (
        SELECT e_id, count(*) as successes FROM e_table
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%success%' AND e_date BETWEEN '23-MAY-2016' AND '26-MAY-2016'
        GROUP BY e_id
    ) s
        on s.e_id = a.e_id
    full outer join
    (
        SELECT e_id, count(*) as failures FROM e_table
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%failure%' AND e_date BETWEEN '23-MAY-2016' AND '26-MAY-2016'
        GROUP BY e_id
    ) f
        on f.e_id = coalesce(a.e_id, s.e_id)
WHERE
    coalesce(attempts, 0) <> coalesce(successes, 0) + coalesce(failures, 0)
```

I changed to full outer joins so you can verify that there are no successes and/or failures without any matching attempt. This should let you find `e_id`s where something's going wrong in the logging. It should be easier to start dealing with finer numbers and not just listings of id values.

Others have pointed out the potential for multiple attempts on the same id but is it conceivable that a success and failure could both be recorded the same way as say in some kind of retry scenario? We don't know what the full comments look like. As a possible explanation, can a single comment can contain more than one of the words "attempt", "success", "failure"?

*Here's something else to consider:* Are you sure that all your success and failures events will fall within the same date window? In other words, is there some delay following the attempt? It might not have to be very long if this happens around midnight. You may want to widen the success and failure ranges enough to compensate for this (and change to left outer joins.)

**Note:** Condition in the `where` clause has been modified to allow for multiple attempts (as noted in comments) and now just looks for a balance in the number of attempts vs. successes and failures.

Comment: I like this answer. I am sure it will help the OP find what's wrong in their data. And the possible flaw concerning the time span is also well spotted.

Comment: I very much like this answer as well. It very clearly shows me all possible e_ids, with the number of attempts, successes, and failures. From here, I can see the orphaned attempts. The only problem is the result set is very large, so I am trying to add a condition like: WHERE attempts - (successes+failures) > 0, which should show only the rows with the orphaned attempts. To address some of your points, there is no "retry" scenario here. There is no possibility of "attempt," "success," or "failure" to be in the same comment. Lastly, the events occur within milliseconds of each other; no delay.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius It seems odd that the results are so big. I'm curious what kind of numbers you were getting.

Comment: A large result set is completely expected; over that three day timespan, there are 5,460 attempts, 5,347 successes, and 50 failures. Your query bunches them together (for e_id's producing multiple transmissions), which is great, but there are still roughly 1000 rows. Again, this is fine, I just need an extra condition to further filter the output.

Comment: @OmnusRuthius Ok, I didn't realize there were multiple transmissions per id.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. For example, e_id 777123 can have three attempts, with two successes and one failure associated with it. All attempts, successes, and failures are related by that e_id. That is the desired behavior. The "which transmission went awry?" question is not what I need answered. If e_id 777123 writes 100 attempts, with 99 successes/failures, I still consider it an **orphan.** Hope that clears things up. If not, let me know. Thanks so much!

Comment: Regarding your edit: excellent. This returns exactly 63 rows, as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your count mismatch stems probably from having multiple attempts per e_id.

Example:

```
Counting:       count (1,1,2,3) - ( count(2) + count(3) ) = 4 - (1 + 1) = 2

Set operations:       (1,1,2,3) - (      (2) +      (3) ) = (1)
```

To get the desired IDs, you'd only have to group by them and compare counts, e.g.:

```
select e_id 
from e_table
where e_date between date'2016-05-23' and date'2016-05-26'
group by e_id
having count(case when e_comment like '%attempt%' then 1 end) >
       count(case when e_comment like '%success%' or e_comment like '%failure%' then 1 end);
```

Don't use strings for dates by the way, but use proper date literals as shown above. (And most of all: never use month names without a proper `to_date` specifying the matching `nls_date_language`.)

Comment: I suppose, this will return 49 rows ;)

Comment: I do not say, that your query is false, actually is the right one, but because of the group by e_id it will give only the distinct e_ids, which I suppose are 49.

Comment: @Mottor: I don't think so. My query would return an e_id with two attempts and only one success or failure. The count query would count 2-1=1, the minus query would not return this e_id. On the other hand my query would return an e_id that has two attempts and no failure once, just like the minus query, whereas the count query would count 2-0=2. So my result may be a number other than both 49 and 63. (SORRY couldn't edit, so I deleted and posted anew.)

Comment: Yes, will be between 49 and 63 depend from the data. The question is, if two attempts with one success is an orphaned attempt?

Comment: @Mottor: Well, we don't know. It's up to the OP to decide what to do in case of multiple attempts per e_id and adjust the having clause accordingly. With my answer I just wanted to second the opinion that there must be duplicate attempts and to show that to query orphaned attempts can be easy. But as to finding the 49/63 mismatch I really like shawnt00's answer with full outer joins showing all counts.

Comment: ERROR: Line 5, Found 'e_comment': Expecting )

Comment: Oops, I missed the keywords `case`. Corrected.

Comment: +1 This works, but takes significantly longer than the selected answer (5 minutes 45 seconds vs. 14 seconds). Thanks! Edit: Interesting...When I change your date condition to event_date >= '23-MAY-2016' AND event_date <= '26-MAY-2016' rather than BETWEEN, it executes in 3 seconds. Any idea why that is?

Comment: This is indead strange as the two expressions are equivalent. Must be a flaw in the optimizer, hence... Or it's because you retrieved the same data the second time and it was in cache when you did.

Answer (score 2):

The query you need would be something like:

```
select e_id
from   e_table e1
where  e_comment like '%attempt%'
and    e_date between date '2016-05-23' and  date '2016-05-26'
and    not exists( select null
                   from   e_table e2
                   where  e2.e_id = e1.e_id
                   and    (e2.e_comment like '%success%' or 
                           e2.e_comment like '%failure%'))
```

The semantics of this seem to match your requirement most closely.

I left the date condition out of the correlated subquery to allow for 
successes and failures outside of the specified window, but it *may* help to add in an extra clause of the form:

```
and e2.e_date >= date '2016-05-23
```

... or ...

```
and e2.e_date >= e1.e_date
```

If you have an index on e_id and the cardinality is close to unique, then performance would not depend on that, however.

Answer (score 1):

Better see what you have per e_id and then decide what to do ;)

```
SELECT e_id,
       count(*) c,
       sum(sign(instr(e_comment, 'attempt'))) c_a, 
       sum(sign(instr(e_comment, 'success'))) c_s, 
       sum(sign(instr(e_comment, 'failure'))) c_f
 FROM e_table
 WHERE e_date >= '23-MAY-2016' AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
GROUP BY e_id
```

Comment: I agree that it makes more sense to do it this way. But I thought OP might be more comfortable with the three individual table queries.

Comment: @shawnt00 This one is for fun. I like sign function   :>)

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE e_comment ( ce_id, e_id, e_comment, e_date ) AS
SELECT '472', '125', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-23 09:49:10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '678', '125', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-23 11:37:09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '724', '125', 'has successfully moved', TIMESTAMP '2016-05-23 11:37:09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '983', '034', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-24 17:04:35' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '643', '672', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-25 13:28:36' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '026', '672', 'failed to move',         TIMESTAMP '2016-05-25 13:28:36' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '087', '672', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-24 18:33:35' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '921', '375', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-26 19:12:43' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '345', '375', 'has successfully moved', TIMESTAMP '2016-05-26 19:12:43' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query - Get the count of the attempts, successes and failures**:

A much simpler query that does not require multiple self-joins:

```
SELECT e_id,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%attempt%' THEN 1 END ) AS attempts,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%success%' THEN 1 END ) AS successes,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%failed%' THEN 1 END ) AS failures
FROM   e_comment
GROUP BY e_id;
```

**Output**:

```
E_ID   ATTEMPTS  SUCCESSES   FAILURES
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
034           1          0          0 
672           2          0          1 
375           1          1          0 
125           2          1          0
```

**Query - Get the orphaned `e_id`s**:

```
SELECT e_id,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%attempt%' THEN 1 END ) AS attempts,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%success%' THEN 1 END ) AS successes,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%failed%' THEN 1 END ) AS failures
FROM   e_comment
GROUP BY e_id
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%attempt%' THEN 1 END )
       <> COUNT( CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%success%' THEN 1 END )
        + COUNT( CASE WHEN e_comment LIKE '%failed%' THEN 1 END );
```

**Output**:

```
E_ID   ATTEMPTS  SUCCESSES   FAILURES
---- ---------- ---------- ----------
034           1          0          0 
672           2          0          1 
125           2          1          0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the row using select where in

```
   select * from e_table 
   where id in (SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT e_id FROM e_table
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%attempt%'
        AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
        AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
    )
    MINUS
    (
        SELECT e_id FROM e_event
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%success%'
        AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
        AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
    )
    MINUS
    (
        SELECT e_id FROM e_event
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%failure%'
        AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
        AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
    ));
```

in this way should obtain all rows involved and easy chack for duplicated id ..

```
   select id, count(*) from e_table 
   where id in (SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT e_id FROM e_table
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%attempt%'
        AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
        AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
    )
    MINUS
    (
        SELECT e_id FROM e_event
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%success%'
        AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
        AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
    )
    MINUS
    (
        SELECT e_id FROM e_event
        WHERE e_comment LIKE '%failure%'
        AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
        AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
    ));
    group by id
    having count(*) >1;
```

in this way you obtain the id more that an entry

Comment: Your second query still returns 49 rows.

Comment: Yes .. of course .. and for each row the number of time this id is repeated .. is correct

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.  It uses a common table expression for clarity, but it's not necessary and could be written with a regular `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

```
WITH 
attempts AS (
    SELECT e_id
    FROM e_table
    WHERE e_comment LIKE '%attempt%'
),
results AS (
    SELECT e_id
    FROM e_table
    WHERE e_comment LIKE '%success%'
       OR e_comment LIKE '%failure%'
)
SELECT a.e_id
FROM attempts a
LEFT OUTER JOIN results r
  ON a.e_id = r.e_id
WHERE r.e_id IS NULL
  AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
  AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016';
```

It joins a list of the attempts to the list of successes/failures.  If the attempt has no matching success/failure and it falls within the desired date range, the corresponding `e_id` is returned.