# Oracle SQL - Isolating Orphaned Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an application that keeps track when a file is being “attempted” to move from one server to another, as well as when it has “succeeded” or “failed.” An "attempt" should always be paired with a "success" or "failure." However, I am encountering orphaned attempts...meaning there have been attempts without any success or failure reported. From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577502/oracle-sql-discrepancy-count-vs-actual-result-set) I asked, I am able to isolate the **e_ids** in particular that are considered orphans. However, I do not want to return the "non-orphaned" transmissions in the final output. Consider the following sample output:

[image]
In the output above, for example, e_id **000125** has a completed transmission (attempt-->success) at time 5/23/2016 11:37:09PM. I do not want to see this. Again, e_id **000672** has a completed transmission(attempt-->failure) at time 5/25/2016 1:28:36PM. I do not want to see this either. I **only** want to see the orphaned transmissions, with a result set looking like this:

[image]

It may be worth noting that all completed transmissions occur within one second of each other (hence why in the first sample output the dates appear as identical, when in reality they differ by milliseconds).

Finally, my query thus far is as follows

```
--This query shows all data for all contact_id's known to be an orphan
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        d.*
    FROM
        (
            SELECT e_id, COUNT(*) AS attempts FROM e_table
            WHERE e_comment LIKE '%attempting%'
            AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
            AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
            GROUP BY e_id
        ) a
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT e_id, COUNT(*) AS successes FROM e_table
            WHERE e_comment LIKE '%successful%'
            AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
            AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
            GROUP BY e_id
        ) s
            ON s.e_id = a.e_id
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT e_id, COUNT(*) AS failures FROM e_table
            WHERE e_comment LIKE '%failed%'
            AND e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
            AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
            GROUP BY e_id
        ) f
            ON f.e_id = COALESCE(a.e_id, s.e_id)
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT * FROM e_table
            WHERE e_date >= '23-MAY-2016'
            AND e_date <= '26-MAY-2016'
        ) d
           ON a.e_id = d.e_id           
    WHERE
        COALESCE(attempts, 0) <> COALESCE(successes, 0) + COALESCE(failures, 0)
)
MINUS
(
    --This is where I'm stuck. I figure, with a MINUS, I can remove the
    --cases with completed transmissions, thus showing ONLY the orphans.
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `'23-MAY-2016'` is not a date - it is a string literal. Oracle will implicitly call `TO_DATE()` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask. If this is not `DD-MON-YYYY` then this will fail and cause the query to error (and the user can alter their session parameters which will cause the query to suddenly fail). It is better to use date literals `DATE '2016-05-23'` or use `TO_DATE()` and explicitly specify the format mask (and since you are using language specific month names you should also specify the NLS language). A date literal is the simpler of the two.

Comment: Thanks - I will use explicit dates once we get the core functionality working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query accomplishes what I need. Instead of using the range specified in the original question, I pull "yesterday's" data:

```
SELECT et.* FROM
(
    SELECT ce_id, e_id FROM e_table et
    WHERE e_comment LIKE ("attempt")
    AND e_date >= TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1))
    AND e_date <= TO_DATE(TRUNC(SYSDATE-1) || ' 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT ce_id, e_id FROM e_table ett
        WHERE e_comment LIKE ("success") OR e_comment LIKE ("failure")
        AND et.e_id = ett.e_id
        AND ett.ce_id > et.ce_id
    ) 
) orphans, e_table et
WHERE orphans.ce_id = et.ce_id
AND orphans.e_id = et.e_id
ORDER BY et.ce_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that does not require any joins; instead it uses the `LEAD` analytic function.

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE e_table ( ce_id, e_id, e_comment, e_date ) AS
SELECT '472', '125', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-23 09:49:10' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '678', '125', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-23 11:37:09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '724', '125', 'has successfully moved', TIMESTAMP '2016-05-23 11:37:09' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '983', '034', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-24 17:04:35' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '643', '672', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-25 13:28:36' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '026', '672', 'failed to move',         TIMESTAMP '2016-05-25 13:28:36' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '087', '672', 'is attempting to move',  TIMESTAMP '2016-05-24 18:33:35' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ce_id,
       e_id,
       e_comment,
       e_date
FROM   (
  SELECT e.*,
         LEAD( e_comment )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY e_id
                  ORDER BY e_date,
                           DECODE( e_comment, 'is attempting to move', 1, 2 )
                ) AS next_comment
  FROM   e_table e
)
WHERE  ( next_comment IS NULL OR next_comment = 'is attempting to move' )
AND    e_comment = 'is attempting to move';
```

**Output**:

```
CE_ID E_ID E_COMMENT              E_DATE                      
----- ---- ---------------------- -----------------------------
983   034  is attempting to move  2016-05-24 17:04:35.000000000 
472   125  is attempting to move  2016-05-23 09:49:10.000000000 
087   672  is attempting to move  2016-05-24 18:33:35.000000000
```

Comment: Thank you MT0, but this does not return the expected number of results.  Again, the sample output I included in my question was just that - a very small sample. There are a total of 5,460 attempts, 5,347 successes, and 50 failures. The expected number of rows, therefore, is 63 rows. This query returns 106, so something is off. I did modify it before executing- adding a WHERE clause in the inner select to consider the date conditions, and changing the comment logic to LIKE '%attempting%,' again as shown in my original question. I had to do this in the DECODE as well.